# Magento 2 luma iphone responsive menu

Tags: ios, magento2, responsive

The luma theme of magento 2 has a bug. 
When iam on an iphone and open the menu the menu opens to far.

It streched past the right side of the screen.

If i do this on android the menu works perfectly.

I was looking at the css code and i found that the menu width was calculated using calc();

It substracted 54px from 100%.
I thought iOs couldn't handle calc but this was not the problem.

Then i tried to fiddled with the width of the parent elements to find the calculation problem.
The problem was that none of it fixed the problem.
And even weirder was the fact that on android it kept working correctly.

Does anyone have this problem also with the luma theme? 
And possibly found a solution.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On our website https://dampershop.nl we solved this problem by changing a bit of css.

We added:

```
html.nav-before-open, .nav-before-open body {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This makes it so that iphone/ios devices opens the responsive menu correctly.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I had the same problem with iOS 9. This solution worked for me. Thanks!